# Using NServiceBus 4.0.2 : Cannot resolve symbol "AsA_Server"

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

I installed NServiceBus using the nuget package manager (Install-Package NServiceBus -Version 4.0.2) and started following along with samples and videos. When I inherit from AsA_Server in my EndPointConfig it says it cannot resolve. What assembly reference am I missing to resolve this?

Comment: There was no solution for me in the answer or any of the comments. What solved it for me was to change the target framework of my project. Pick the full .Net Framework 4 iso the default .Net Framework 4 client profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am only guessing but you probably need the **NServiceBus Host** package to be also nugeted. If it doesn't work, try also the NServiceBus Interfaces.

Comment: Install-Package NServiceBus.Host -Version 4.0.2

Comment: However, you shouldn't be implementing AsA_Server on a message handler, only on the EndpointConfig class!

Comment: Right you are! Thanks for the help and clarification.